# Possible msvc/intellisense bug with variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, intellisense

I am using VS2015 Update 3. The following piece of code gives an intellisense error on the lines in main(), however the code compiles and runs without error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

// Template parameter classes
template<class...> struct ComponentList {};   
template<class...> struct Filter {};
template<class...> struct FilterList {};

template<typename ATuple, typename BTuple>
class EntityManager;

template<class... A, template<class> class... B>
class EntityManager<ComponentList<A...>, FilterList<B...>>
{
public:
    template<class A>
    void test()
    {
        std::cout << typeid(A).name() << std::endl;
    }

    // Create tuple for each filter inside filterlist
    std::tuple<B...> tuples;
};

using MyComponents = ComponentList<int, double, float>;
using FirstFilter = Filter<int, double>;
using SecondFilter = Filter<float>;
using MyFilters = FilterList<FirstFilter, SecondFilter>;

void main()
{
    EntityManager<MyComponents, MyFilters> em;
    em.test<int>();
}
```

On the first line of main, intellisense says 'incomplete type is not allowed'.

On the second line, intellisense gives three errors: 'incomplete type is not allowed', 'type name is not allowed', and 'expected an expression'

Is this a bug in the compiler or in intellisense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some problems.

Try (1) defining `EntityManager` as

```
template<class... A, class... B>
class EntityManager<ComponentList<A...>, FilterList<B...>>
```

(because `FirstFilter` and `SecondFilter` are typenames, non `template<class> class` parameters) and (2) using a different template parameter for `test()` (`A` conflict with `A...` for class)

```
template<class C>
void test()
{
    std::cout << typeid(C).name() << std::endl;
}
```

and (3) adding `#include<typeinfo>` and (4) defining `int main()` instead of `void main()`.

Comment: Changing the definition of EntityManager made the intellisense errors go away, so I suppose this is a bug in Intellisense? Thank you for your other improvements. I didn't know void main() was only accepted by msvc, and that I had to include <typeinfo> before using typeid.

Comment: @M.Bijman - I don't know Intellisense so I don't know if it's a error in Intellisense; I know only that your first version was wrong